# Invalid Syntax with name input

Tags: python, syntax

I'm new to programming and Python. I am attempting to write my first program, however I keep getting an "Invalid Syntax" error for these few lines of code. This is all I am trying to get down pat. When I written this, it was in IDLE for Python 3.6.1

```
name = raw_input ("Please tell me your name: ")
print ("Hello "+ name)
print "Your name is:" + str(len(name)) "letters long"
```

Can you guys please give me a hand for this? Also I like more information around Syntax errors because I heard they happen often. What are they?

Comment: You're missing a '+' in the third line.

Comment: raw_input() was changed to input() in Python 3.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping stackoverflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: Also, print() is a function in Python 3, so your line #3 is invalid.  Please go through a Python tutorial to understand the basics.

Comment: Whatever tutorial you are learning is teaching you Python 2, not Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you lost a plus in your code,

```
name = raw_input ("Please tell me your name: ")
print ("Hello "+ name)
print "Your name is:" + str(len(name)) "letters long"
                                   #  ^ There should be a "+" ?
```

The right code should be:

```
name = raw_input ("Please tell me your name: ")
print ("Hello "+ name)
print "Your name is:" + str(len(name)) + "letters long"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with it from the beginning, I'd recommend you check out [A Byte of Python](https://python.swaroopch.com/) as it gives a solid understanding of Python and caters it to newbies.

As for your actual issue `print` is no longer a keyword in Python 3 and requires the use of parenthesis `print("thing")` as opposed to `print "thing"`

A second issue I spotted is that `raw_input` is now `input` in Python 3 so that also needs to be changed.

To avoid the final issue which seems to be the lack of a `+` when you concatenate the string, use the `str.format()` method or perhaps Python 3.6's `f` strings.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar happen, when I added a script to a /bin directory.

my issue was that at the start I had:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

- that called python2

when I needed:

`#!/usr/bin/env python3`

- that actually calls a python3 environment